# Why is string returned from promise undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a function that calls a firestore function:

```
const getConvoId = (ownerId, withId) => {
    return firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('user-conversations')
        .where('owner', '==', ownerId)
        .where('withId', '==', withId)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
            if (querySnapshot.empty == true) {
                return null;
            } else {
                // have also tried "return"ing the querSnapshot.forEach() but behavior is the same
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    console.log('DOC-ID => ' + doc.id);
                    return doc.id;
                });
            }
        });
};
```

Implemented as such:

```
const getConvoScenario = (senderUid, receiverUid) => {
    const convoIds = {};
    return getConvoId(senderUid, receiverUid).then((result) => {
        convoIds.sender = result;
        // if result is null, it logs null, if the result exists, it logs 'undefined'
        console.log('\nSENDER-CONVO-ID => ' + result);
    });
};
```

The issue is that when calling `getConvoId()`, when it finds a doc-id (proven by logging it from inside the function), the `result` is undefined, but if the a doc-id couldn't be found, `result` is defined as 'null'.

Why is `result` logging as undefined in the parent function when the doc-id is logged successfully and returned from the child function, but `result` works as expected when getConvoId() returns null?

EDIT:

```
return querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log('DOC-ID => ' + doc.id);
    return doc.id;
});
```

^ **has the same result** ^

```
return querySnapshot.map((doc) => {
    console.log('DOC-ID => ' + doc.id);
    return doc.id;
});
```

^ **results in a type error. `querySnapshot.map is not a function. querySnapshot.map is undefined`** ^

Comment: Missing a return at `return querySnapshot.forEach` you need to return the valuye of the `forEach` be aware it might be an Array and not a string

Comment: I thought so too, but I tried: `else {
    return querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
     console.log('USER-CONVO FOUND. DOC-ID => ' + doc.id);
     return doc.id;
    });
   }` and the behavior is the same

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return anything

Comment: `forEach` returns `doc.id`. and in the else clause, querySnapshot.forEach() is returned without change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `return` statement inside your `then` callback. The `return` statement in the `forEach` loop will only return a value inside the array, but the array is never returned.

Instead of the `forEach` use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which will create a new array based on the returned value inside the loop. So in the example below you would return an array with the `doc.id` values.

```
const getConvoId = (ownerId, withId) => firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection('user-conversations')
  .where('owner', '==', ownerId)
  .where('withId', '==', withId)
  .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    if (querySnapshot.empty == true) {
      return null;
    } 
    return querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
      console.log('DOC-ID => ' + doc.id);
      return doc.id;
    });;
  });
```

Comment: switching `forEach()` to `map()` and adding `return`  before querySnapshot.map() results in a TypeError. `querySnapshot.map is not a function. querySnapshot.map Is undefined.`

Comment: What type of value is `querySnapshot`? If it does not support `map` then it cannot be an array, so we'll have to figure out how to return the values based on the type of the value it is.

Comment: just confirmed on Firebase's Firestore docs: `collection.where()` returns a `Query` object, then `get()` return a promise containing a `QuerySnapshot` object, which has access to the forEach method. so if it weren't truly a query snapshot object, it wouldn't have access to the `empty` property.

Comment: querySnapshot is a QuerySnapshot object in Firebase's firestore api

Comment: Thank you. It turns out that the `QuerySnapshot` objects has a property `docs` which holds all the `QueryDocumentSnapshot` objects in an array. If the docs are correct then using `map` on the `docs` property should work.

Comment: ahh I see. Im still confused why return on `.forEach()` didn't work

Comment: According to the docs the `forEach` function does not return a value. Returning a function which does not return a value will give `undefined` as a result.